# Systemd + non-root Gunicorn service = defunct subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, gunicorn, systemd

I'm following [this document](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.4.5/deploy.html#systemd) to setup a Systemd socket and service for my gunicorn server.

- Systemd starts gunicorn as `www-data`
- gunicorn forks itself (default behavior)
- the server starts a subprocess with `subprocess.Popen()`
- the subprocess finishes without an error, but the parent keeps getting None from from `p.poll()` instead of an exit code
- the subprocess ends up defunct

Here's the process hierarchy:

```
$ ps eauxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
...
www-data 14170  0.0  0.2  65772 20452 ?        Ss   10:57   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn digits.webapp:app --pid /run/digits/pid --config /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/digits/gunicorn_config.py
www-data 14176  0.8  3.4 39592776 283124 ?     Sl   10:57   0:05  \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn digits.webapp:app --pid /run/digits/pid --config /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/digits/gunicorn_config.py
www-data 14346  5.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    11:07   0:01      \_ [python] <defunct>
```

**Here's the kicker**: when I run the service as `root` instead of `www-data`, everything works as expected. The subprocess finishes and the parent immediately gets the child's return code.

`/lib/systemd/system/digits.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=DIGITS daemon
Requires=digits.socket
After=local-fs.target network.target
[Service]
PIDFile=/run/digits/pid
User=www-data
Group=www-data
Environment="DIGITS_JOBS_DIR=/var/lib/digits/jobs"
Environment="DIGITS_LOGFILE_FILENAME=/var/log/digits/digits.log"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn digits.webapp:app \
    --pid /run/digits/pid \
    --config /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/digits/gunicorn_config.py
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/lib/systemd/system/digits.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=DIGITS socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/digits/socket
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:34448
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/digits.conf`

```
d /run/digits 0755 www-data www-data -
```

Comment: I gave up and stopped using gunicorn for now. I'll need to solve this someday though, so if anybody has any ideas please let me know!

Comment: I have the same freaking issue all day today. And I followed this document (similar to the one you pointed out) to the letter: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html (._.) Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue today on **CentOS-7**. I finally overcame it by ignoring the instructions in [this document](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) -- which indicates to use the `/run/` hierarchy within which to create the socket -- and I instead used `/tmp/`. That worked.

Note that my PID file is still placed underneath `/run/` (no issues there).

In summary, instead of placing your socket somewhere underneath `/run/...`, try placing it somewhere underneath `/tmp/...` instead. It worked for me on **CentOS-7** with **systemd**.